# c# process "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Tags: c#, process, null

I'm trying to create an automatized tool for database backup. My code works fine on a server but on another one I have this error. Please help me solve it.

My code:

```
using (Process mySqlDump = new Process())
{
    try
    {
        string
        user =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySqlUser"],
        pwd =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySqlPassword"],
        server =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"],
        database =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"],
        savepath;

        savepath = database + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy-hh.mm.ss") + ".sql";
        savepath = savepath.Replace("/", "-");
        savepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaveLocation"] + savepath;

        mySqlDump.StartInfo.FileName = @"mysqldump.exe";
        mySqlDump.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        mySqlDump.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-u" + user + " -p" + pwd + " -h" + server + " " + database + " -r \"" + savepath + "\"";
        mySqlDump.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        mySqlDump.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        mySqlDump.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        mySqlDump.Start();
        mySqlDump.WaitForExit();
        mySqlDump.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I understood that if the process is already opened, the code will try to use it instead of opening another instance so the variable will be `null` (in my case mySqlDump). So, i tried to force close the already opened proces with:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(@"mysqldump.exe"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

What is wrong in my code? Why is not working?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Could you post your stack trace please

Comment: What error message you are getting?

Comment: The problem is at line mySqlDump.Start();. I got the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" because mySqlDump seems to be null. On the other server, the code works just fine.

Comment: If `mySqlDump` was null, the first reference (`mySqlDump.StartInfo.FileName = @"mysqldump.exe";`) would have thrown the exception. Moreover, you're using `using (Process mySqlDump = new Process())` which is initializing the variable ensuring it's not null. Maybe paste the stack trace?

Comment: I don't have any stack trace because on my computer works fine. I'll log it and tomorrow i'll come back with the stack trace.

Comment: SOLVED. The real problem was that the mysqldump.exe couldn't be found. I had to edit locations in Environment Variables in order to solve this problem.